# Reeb Graph of Topological Space and Lemma about Induced map Between Homologies

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

I am a physicist following a course in Topological Data Analysis (MasterMath), and I need to prove the following lemma about the graphs. I know I am supposed to write what I have tried, but honestly I feel lost.

### Definition of Reeb Graphs

[image]

### Lemma

[image]